# How to change device locale language setting of device?

Tags: android, settings, locale

I want to convert my android project to multiple language. I have created a list view where different languages are going to be shown. I want to change the device language when I select any item from this list. How can I do this?

Comment: Check this link.

Please search before ask.


  


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657106/changing-the-language-of-app-without-changing-the-settings-of-device

Answer (score 2):

You can change the the Language like this

```
    Locale locale = new Locale("en_US");
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    context.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me. The language on com.android.settings app stays the same.